# GWT MVP History back

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp, gwt-history

I have a MVP application implemented. Back button is working fine. 
I'd like to programatically go back to the previous place. How would I do that?

I'm looking for something like:

```
clientFactory.getPlaceController().goBack();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the native GWT history for that:

```
History.back();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PlaceManager, you can call navigateBack() on an instance of PlaceManager.

Comment: (which is a wrapper for History.back() according to the javadoc)